# Enviar datos de un post de wordpress a un php externo

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, wordpress-plugin

Que tal muchachos quisiera enviar los datos de un post recien creado a un php externo con el action de wordpress, pero no se como hacerlo, he intentado con ajax pero al parecer no se ejecuta

```
function enviar_datos( $post_id ) {
    $post_title = get_the_title( $post_id );
    //enviar variable $post_title a un php en otro servidor
}
add_action('publish_post', 'enviar_datos', 20);
```

Como podria hacerlo?
ya he intentado con ajax y no funciona

```
wp_register_script(
        'your-script', 
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/ajax_test.js', 
        array('jquery') 
    );

function enviar_datos( $post_id ) {
    var titulo = $post_title = get_the_title( $post_id );
    $params = array (
      'varHome' => titulo
  );

wp_enqueue_script('your-script');
wp_localize_script('your-script','vars_inline',$params);
}
add_action('publish_post', 'enviar_datos', 1);


AJAX
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
var datos =vars_inline.varHome;
jQuery.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: 'http://ejemplo.com/pruebas/index.php',
  data: { datosz: datos },
  success: function( data ) {
    console.log(data);
  }
});
})
```

O si saben de algún plugin que dispare un evento cuando se cree un nuevo post y me envié los datos

Gracias de antemano

Comment: <?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

Comment: el wordpress http y el de las consultas tambien en http

Comment: Si, porque inicialmente me aparecio error por el Cors, con esto ya se soluciono

Comment: Ya lo solucione con un plugin "Notification – Custom Notifications and Alerts for WordPress" tiene un apartado de webhooks para hacer exactamente lo q yo necesitaba, Muchas gracias